# Why mat-spinner not showing?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-7

Index.html file is:

```
<body>
    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</body>
```

App.module file is:

```
@NgModule({

 imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
]
})
```

I see on the page tag `<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>` but it does not work, no any errors in console

Comment: You put spinner in your index.html ? You must put it under angular views

Comment: you can show a spinner with full CSS while Angular is loading. So you don't need Angular to render it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular components can't be rendered on their own inside the index.html file.
That's why default AppComponent is bootstrapped through main.ts file.

You should include the mat-spinner inside an Angular Component.
If the spinner is meant to be displayed on application boostraping, you must use a custom spinner which can then be included in the index.html :

```
<app-root><div id="spinner"></div></app-root>
```

To display a spinner when lazy loading a module on routing, you can listen to `router.events` in the component containing the `<router-outlet>`:

```
loading: boolean;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.loading = true;
      }
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationError || event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

and display conditionally your spinner :

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="loading"></mat-spinner>
```

here is a stackblitz example (but the spinner isn't displayed as the modules are loaded too quickly) : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xwd2ta?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I try to show spinner until lazy module is loading, when it loaded it replace <app-root> content

Comment: Could I use it like `<app-root><mat-spinner></mat-spinner></app-root>`

Comment: you can't use content projection on the app-root selector as it's declared outside of the angular scope.

Comment: How then to use loader for lazy loading modules

Comment: you can add it inside the appComponent html file and listen to the router.events in order to catch the NavigationSatr and NavigationEnd event in order to act on a conditional rendering

Comment: I have some modules ,and I dont want to duplicate code in each components

Comment: Thank you, buu your example dose not hide loader after loaded

Comment: it does on NavigationEnd => this.loading = false

Comment: It always false: `{{ loading }}` when I reload page f5

Comment: You talked about a need on lazy loaded modules ('How then to use loader for lazy loading modules"). This solution is when you route to a lazy loaded route, not on f5

Comment: for spinner on application boostraping, you can include it inside the app-root selector : `<app-root><div id="spinner></div></app-root>"` with some styling but it can't be a `mat-spinner` as it needs to be inside the angular scope

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue of not showing mat-spinner in sub-component not in index.html.
I am using `@angular/cli@14.0.0` i.e. **Angular 14**.

To resolve this issue, I had to delete `node_modules` folder and remove `@angular/material` and `@angular/cdk dependencies` from `package.json` (simply uninstall highlighted packges/modules)

there after add them back with command

> ng add @angular/cdk@^14.0.0

> ng add @angular/material^@14.0.0

the above command will ask

1. *prebuilt themes* choose **custom**
2. *typography* choose **No**
3. *animation* choose **Yes**

`ng add` because installing these packages with `npm install -save @angular/cdk @angular/material` won't work